# How do I find the longest list in a list of lists?

Tags: list, prolog

I have a list of lists, and I need to find the longest one of them. If there are more than one with the same length it's the same which it returns. Thanks.

Comment: Can you write a 3-place predicate that compares two lists and "returns" the one that is longer?

Comment: Hmm, maybe. I'll look at it later. Have a lecture now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a general predicate that scans a list to find a single member defined by a given goal.

```
select_element(Goal, [Head | Tail], Selected) :-
    select_element(Goal, Tail, Head, Selected).


select_element(_Goal, [], Selected, Selected).

select_element(Goal, [Head | Tail], Current, FinalSelected) :-
    call(Goal, Head, Current, Selected),
    select_element(Goal, Tail, Selected, FinalSelected).
```

Lets say you define a predicate

```
get_bigger_number(N1, N2, N) :-
    N is max(N1, N2).
```

Now you can execute:

```
?- select_element(get_bigger_number, [5, 1, -2, 10, 3.2, 0], Selected).

Selected = 10
```

So all you need to do now is define a predicate `get_longer_list(L1, L2, L)`,
and use it instead of `get_bigger_number/3`.

Of course, using a general predicate like `select_element/3` might not be very efficient. For example, you should try to avoid calculating the length of the same list several times, because this calculation is slow in Prolog (at least if implemented in Prolog in the standard way).

Comment: I'm not sure how this would be if the number are actual lists. Because the head of the list would be a a list.

Comment: select_element/3 does not care what is the nature (e.g. atomic or list) of the list elements. Everything depends on the predicate that you have to write (get_longer_list/3).

Answer (score 2):

Please consider my aproach.

```
longest([L], L) :-
   !.
longest([H|T], H) :- 
   length(H, N),
   longest(T, X),
   length(X, M),
   N > M,
   !.
longest([H|T], X) :-
   longest(T, X),
   !.
```

Then you can consult it:

```
?- longest([[1]], N).
N = [1] ;

?- longest([[1],[2]], N).
N = [2] .

?- longest([[1],[2], [3,3,3], [2]], N).
N = [3, 3, 3] ;

?- longest([[1],[2], [3,3,3], [2]], N).
N = [3, 3, 3].

?- longest([[1],[2], [3,3,3], [2], [4,4,4,4]], N).
N = [4, 4, 4, 4] .

?- longest([[1],[2], [3,3,3], [2], [4,4,4,4]], N).
N = [4, 4, 4, 4] ;
```

Greets!

Comment: Of course, you can also validate that the manipulated objects are actually lists.

Comment: The complexity of your solution is O(n^2). That's too much for a simple problem like this...

Comment: The goal `longest([[1],[2]],[1])` fails. It *should* succeed!

Answer (score 2):

We define `longest/2` based on  [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`max_of_by/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31850246/4609915) used in tandem with [`length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2):

```
longest(Xss,Ys) :-
   max_of_by(Ys,Xss,length).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- longest([[1],[2]],Xs).      % we expect   multiple solutions
  Xs = [1]                
; Xs = [2].                    % we    _get_ multiple solutions

?- longest([[2,1,3],[7,5],[1,8,2,3,1],[2,7,1,4]],Xs).
Xs = [1,8,2,3,1].              % succeeds deterministically
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that is efficient and easy to understand. The idea is to find the lengths of all lists in the list, use `max_list` to get the length of the longest list, and then find a list that is that long. This has the benefit that it will return all lists of the longest length.

```
lengths([],[]).
lengths([H|T], [LH|LengthsT]) :-
    length(H, LH),
    lengths(T, LengthsT).

lengthLongest(ListOfLists, Max) :-
    lengths(ListOfLists, Lengths),
    max_list(Lengths, Max).

longestList(ListOfLists, Longest) :-
    lengthLongest(ListOfLists, Len),
    member(Longest, ListOfLists),
    length(Longest, Len).
```

Comment: s(X) for returning **all** lists of maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

To have the length of longest list:

```
%sample: longest([[2,1,3],[7,5],[1,8,2,3,1],[2,7,1,4]],L,LEN).

longest([L], L, _) :-
   !.
longest([H|T], H, _) :-
   length(H, N),
   longest(T, X, N),
   length(X, M),
   N > M,
   !.
longest([_|T], X, LEN) :-
   length(X, LEN),
   longest(T, X, LEN),
   !.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% Correct again.

longest(LL,LX) :-
        findmax(Len,(append(_,[L|_],LL),length(L,Len)),MaxLen),
        append(_,[LX|_],LL),
        length(LX,MaxLen).

findmax(V,P,Max) :-
        findall(V,P,L),
        max(L,Max).

max([N],N) :- !.
max([N|R],Max) :-
        max(R,Max2),
        max3(N,Max2,Max).

max3(N,Max2,N) :- N > Max2,!.
max3(N,Max2,Max2).
```